# Using React states with delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-easy-state

I am using a library called `react-easy-state` for my state management but I believe this questions is not directly related to this library rather a general question.

Having a code like this in my App.js :

```
function App() {
  const [isChanged, setIsChanged] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(store.counter);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsChanged(true);
    }, store.counter);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isChanged && <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>}
      <Change />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which has a child `<Changed />` that looks like this :

```
export default function Change() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    store.rndNum = ~~(Math.random() * 6) + 11;
  }, []);

  store.counter = ~~Math.pow(1.555, store.rndNum) * 20;
```

The child is supposed to generate a random number and then modify the random number and store it in another variable in my store. The modified value is supposed to slow down the appearance of an HTML element which toggled and triggered by `setTimeout`. However my console shows that number that is being generated is not matching with my code and as it generates `20` for some reason and then proceeds to generate the correct number. In the mean time I would like to wait until the value in my store in updated and then run `setTimeout`. Whereas currently `setTimeout` takes either `0` or `20` as the timer and executes the code without any delay.

code to reproduce : https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cdn-vg7kh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting 20 first because of this operation.

```
store.counter = ~~Math.pow(1.555, store.rndNum) * 20;
```

Why? Because store.rndNum at that time is still "" (declared on store as "") and this part

```
~~Math.pow(1.555, store.rndNum)
```

will always be 1.

Hooks are asynchronous, so useEffect will not change the rndNum value first.

Edit for my comment:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isNaN(store.rndNum)) {
      store.counter = ~~Math.pow(1.555, store.rndNum) * 20;
    }
  }, [store.rndNum]);
```

Comment: So how am I supposed to achieve the desired results ?

Comment: You should call another useEffect hook but with "store.rndNum" in the dependency array. So there you make sure that when you get a value there, then you calculate the counter.

Comment: Could you add a sample code for that ? I would really appreciate it.